# installed check for c but "check.h" not found

Tags: c, windows, ubuntu, makefile, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Im using windows 10 with wsl ubuntu 18.04 Im trying to run the code from here :
https://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/skotthe/classes/cs5600/fall/2015/labs/intro-check-lab-code.tgz

I installed gcc, makefile, and check in the ubuntu terminal. But when I di `$ make` it says:

```
gcc money.o check_money.o -lcheck -lm -lpthread -lrt  -lgcov -coverage -o check_money_tests
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcheck.a(check_log.o): In function `subunit_lfun':
(.text+0x5f4): undefined reference to `subunit_test_start'
(.text+0x6bf): undefined reference to `subunit_test_fail'
(.text+0x6d4): undefined reference to `subunit_test_pass'
(.text+0x6ef): undefined reference to `subunit_test_error'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:23: recipe for target 'check_money_tests' failed
make: *** [check_money_tests] Error 1
```

so I open the check_money.c it says that `check.h` cannot be found. What did I miss here?

Comment: This is a linker failure, so you're missing the definitions for those `subunit_*` functions. Is there an additional library you have to link in or compile?

Comment: @tadman I think the missing library is check library. But I've installed it in wsl, and I also compiled this from wsl.

Comment: You need to include that as another `-l` flag, or compile it and link it in somehow. Consult the documentation for that code. I don't know where it came from. Installing the library is only half of the solution.

Comment: Where does it say that `check.h` cannot be found? The error messages you show, don't say that. Is it only your editor that is unable to find it?

Comment: I think all `subunit_test_***` is from `check.h`. I think this means my check.h is actually found but doesnt contain these functions ?

Comment: First install the subunit lib: `sudo apt-get install libsubunit-dev`, then link with the lib.

Answer (score 2):

Simple version: you should also link with `-lsubunit` flag, i.e.:

```
TST_LIBS = -lcheck -lm -lpthread -lrt -lsubunit
```

Better yet, all the flags should be taken from `check`'s package configuration, as the requirements depend on how the `check` library was built (and that's what `pkg-config` has been invented for). So instead of hardcoding your options, you could improve your `Makefile` like this:

```
CFLAGS = -c -Wall $(shell pkg-config --cflags check)
TST_LIBS = $(shell pkg-config --libs check)
```

Result:

```
$ make
gcc -c -Wall -pthread -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage src/*.c
gcc -c -Wall -pthread -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage  tests/*.c
gcc money.o check_money.o -lcheck_pic -pthread -lrt -lm -lsubunit -lgcov -coverage -o check_money_tests
...
```

Comment: This is how to install `subunit` if you don't have it on Linux Ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install libsubunit-dev`